# Training a logistic regression in Mahout strange behaviour

Tags: mahout, logistic-regression

I'm trying to train a logistic regression model in mahout. The command I use is this:`mahout trainlogistic --input /home/cloudera/Desktop/final.csv --output /home/cloudera/Desktop/model/model --target Action --predictors Open High Close --types word --features 20 --passes 100 --rate 50 --categories 2`

The files I use actually exist. I'm reading a book that says that I should expect an output that looks like

> Action ~ 647.186*Close+-44.975*High+3.269*Intercept term +-601.454*Open

and then a 4x2 matrix.

What I actually get is a terminal being filled with calculations, no `Action ~`, and a 5x4 matrix.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `type` of my predictors was `numeric`; why did the book I referenced call them `words` I have no idea.